# Reduzir o tempo de execução na simulação em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Oi. Estou tentando resolver um problema onde tenho que criar uma função que recebe uma string de 0 e 1 e uma lista de comandos, que podem ser `'I'` e `'Q'`.
Caso seja `'I'` o programa deve modificar todos os valores dentro dos limites indicados e caso seja `'Q'` devo adicionar o elemento indicado a uma lista. Por exemplo:

```py
binary_simulation("0011001100", [['I', 1, 10], ['I', 2, 7], ['Q', 2], ['Q', 1], ['Q', 7], ['Q', 5]])
```

Isso deve nos retornar: `['0','1','1','0']`

Acontece que já consegui resolver o problema, mas ele excede o limite de tempo execução do site. Queria saber se teria como reduzir mais o tempo de execução do meu código. Segue ele:

```py
def binary_simulation(s, q):
    lst = []
    for e in q:
        if(e[0] == 'I'):
            for j in range(e[1]-1,e[2],1):
                if ( s[j] == '1'):
                    s = s[:j] + '0' + s[j+1:]
                else:
                    s = s[:j] + '1' + s[j+1:]
        else:
            lst.append(s[e[1]-1])
    return lst
```

Agradeço, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa operação:

```
s = s[:j] + '1' + s[j+1:]
```

Isso é algo muuuuito lento. Basicamente ele cria uma lista nova inteirinha copiando todos os elementos um por um e só trocando um deles lá no meio. Se houver 1.000.000 de elementos, fazer isso várias e várias vezes vai detonar o seu tempo.

Tente algo assim:

```py
def binary_simulation(s, q):
    u = []
    for x in s:
        u.append(x)
    lst = []
    for e in q:
        if e[0] == 'I':
            for j in range(e[1] - 1, e[2]):
                u[j] = ('0' if u[j] == '1' else '1')
        else:
            lst.append(u[e[1] - 1])
    return lst
```

A ideia é usar uma lista ao invés de uma string (a variável `u`), pois listas são mutáveis e portanto, você pode alterá-las a vontade sem ter que reconstruir uma outra nova sempre que quiser mudar um elemento.

Comment: Entendi, Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @DiegoN Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.